# How to create a custom protobuf library?

Tags: java, protobuf-java

**Requirement**: I need a gradle project (**parent project**) which has some common .proto files along with their respected java generated classes which will be added as a dependency to another project (**child project**) where I have some more .proto files in which I need to import the .proto files of **parent project** and generate the respective java classes.

**Problem**: After importing the proto files and generating respective java classes, I am getting an error (**package not found**) in generated java classes where I have imported a particular .proto file of parent project.

**What I tried**:

1. Created a parent project with .proto files at path src/main/java and generated java classes at path src/main/java.
2. Prepared a jar of the parent project and added it as a dependency in child project.
3. I am able to import the .proto file of parent project in child project .proto file.
4. Getting the error (package not found) after generating the java classes.

**Observations**:

1. The parent jar is having only the class files.
2. If I include only src/main in parent jar and use it in the child project, I am not facing the package not found error.

**Environments**:

1. I am currently trying it out in local, as in, generating the jar files and putting it in the lib folder of the project and importing the same in dependencies.

**Build tool**: Gradle

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!